# Risks of using device body as heat sink for IGBT and Bridge rectifier

Tags: igbt, bridge, electricity, shock

I want to know is any risk factor (electrical shocking or ... ) for using one aluminum (4mm) device body which is used as heat-sink for IGBT and Bridge rectifier that are working with 220 volt power?
is use a silicon layer between those surface how is it? (guess withstand temperatures up to 260°C (500 °F))

thanks a lot.

Comment: I've not seen an IGBT or rectifier that'd survive 260'C *while operational* (most are only rated to 150'C, some 175'C but that's as high as I've ever seen). For a few seconds while soldering, yes, but don't grill it for extended periods. The back side of many (but not all) IGBTs is electrically connected to the drain, so unless you *want* the chassis at the same voltage potential as the drain, then an insulating pad is a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously there are two primary risks: shock and temperature.

For shock, any mains-connnected circuitry MUST be double-insulated. — in other words, there must be at least two independent layers of insulation, each of which is capable of withstanding the peak voltage on its own.

For temperature, you must make sure that no exposed surfaces ever get hot enough to cause burns, or worse yet, to ignite any flammable materials. If the heatsink gets too hot on its own, sometimes it makes sense to put a shroud around it and blow air across it with a fan.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious risk is shock if the part of the case the heatsink is connected to is at dangerous voltage.  A thin insulating layer, like a silicon sheet for that purpose, between the part and the heatsink is not considered safe.  I've seen such things fail on occasion.

The better way to deal with this is to consider the heatsink to be at dangerous voltage and insulate it from the outside accordingly.